# One angle of the triangle must be..

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

In a triangle ABC the altitudes from B and C on the opposite sides are not shorter than their respective opposite sides. then one of the angle of the triangle ABC is?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, "Less than $180^\circ$" is clearly correct, but at the same time probably not what you're looking for. What kind of answer are you really after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a triangle, an altitude is not greater than any of the two sides with the same vertex. In our case, if $BH$ and $CK$ are the altitudes, we have then:
$$
BH\le AB 
\quad\hbox{and}\quad 
CK\le AC.
$$
On the other hand we know that
$$
BH\ge AC
\quad\hbox{and}\quad 
CK\ge AB.
$$
Combining the above inequalities we get:
$$
AB\ge AC
\quad\hbox{and}\quad 
AB\le AC,
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
AB=AC. 
$$
Thus $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle, which entails $BH=CK$. We have then:
$$
BH\le AB\le CK = BH,
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
BH=AB.
$$
We come then to the conclusion that in our triangle altitudes $BH$ and $CK$ are the same as sides $AB$ and $AC$, which can happen only if $\angle BAC=90°$.